# Multiple lines of data, want to get an index or figure out how to get it in order

Tags: python, list

1. reads and stores the data in this file.
2. User for two integers corresponding to start and end years, and finds and lists the year of publication, title, author, in that order, of all books published during that period.
3. It repeats the previous step till the user enters -1 when prompted for the start year.

This is what I have so far (see picture)

```
def main(): 
    file = open("resources.txt","r") 
    myList = [] 
    year1 = int(input("Enter the first year:")) 
    year2 = int(input("Enter the second year: ")) 
    for x in range(year1, year2): 
        print(yearofpublication,title, author)
```

and the file is 1000 lines

I need help with #2 mainly.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: I just added the code, I'm using Pycharm

Comment: Please add a sample of your data as text along with their column headers. @Stephen Creed

Comment: Hey @AnkurSaxena the sample of my data i presented, that is just  a portion of it and there is no column header. They are "Title of book", "Authors" and "year of publication"

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that doesn't uses Pandas. I have put comments to break down the code according to the steps you requested. Step 1 imports the text file, gets rid of all tabs and newline characters and splits each line on the semicolon to create a list of lists.
Step 2 iterates through all the books and compares index 3 (year) of each book to the specified years.  Step 3 creates an infinite loop and breaks it only when the user enters -1.

```
#step 1
data = open('resources.txt', 'r')
book_list = []
for line in data:
    new_line = line.rstrip('\n').replace('\t', '').split(';')
    book_list.append(new_line)
#step 3
while True:
    year1 = int(input("Enter the first year:"))
    if year1 == -1:
        break
    year2 = int(input("Enter the second year: "))
    #step2
    for book in book_list:
        if year1 <= int(book[3]) <= year2:
            print(f'Publication Year: {book[3]}, Title: {book[1]}, Author: {book[2]}')
```

Comment: thanks so much @pakpe I see how you went through a did each step

Comment: I tried this code and it keeps giving me a book_list is not defined function

Comment: @StephenCreed book_list is a list, not a function. The code works. I tried it multiple times. Copy my code and paste it to troubleshoot the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a txt file like below that is `;` separated with a consistent format and no headers.

```
1   ;   A   ; X ;1220
2   ;   B   ; Y ;1245
```

You can load the file using pandas which will allow you to easily filter the data on conditions.

```
import pandas
df = pandas.read_csv("data.txt", sep=";", names=["id", "author", "title", "year"])
```

Then for your step 2, you can filter the dataframe based on `year1` and `year2`

```
df[(df['year'] > year1) & (df['year'] < year2)]
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Thank you for your take on trying to get this to work. Could you maybe dumb it down for me in terms of what everything means? Also is there a way I could write it without using pandas

Comment: Without pandas, you will have to read the file, split each line by `;` and store the values in a list. Then for every (year1, year2) you'll filter the list for values lying in between those two. You can update your question to specify without pandas solution and maybe show some work based on what I suggested. I'll be happy to help you further.

Comment: I should've been more clear about not using pandas, thank you so much for your contribution, you gave me a different view on how to look at this program. your time is appreciated.